# Translating http requests from cURL to Node http.request

Tags: node.js, curl

I'm having some trouble with basic auth in Node.

Here's how I can do it via cURL as child process:

```
var auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString('base64');
var url =  'https://' + hostname + path;

var curlstr = "curl #{url} -H 'Authorization: #{auth}'"
  .replace('#{url}', url)
  .replace('#{auth}', auth);

require('child_process').exec(curlstr, function (err, stdout, stderr){
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

But it's returning 403s when I try https.request:

```
var req = https.request({
  hostname: hostname,
  path: path,
  headers: {'Authorization': auth}
}, function (res){
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});

req.end();
```

And I get the same results with [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request):

```
request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: url,
  auth: {
    username: username,
    password: password
  }
}, function (err,res,body){
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I suspect the error is happening with your HTTPS server, could you share that code?

Comment: It'd be helpful to log the request headers on the HTTPS server if you're able to do that. In that way you can check whether you're sending the auth info you *think* you're sending. Also check out the [`sendImmediately` parameter](https://github.com/mikeal/request#http-authentication) of `request`

Comment: I don't have any control over the server with which I am communicating, but I'll try sending the requests to a test server so I can see how the requests differ.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's https, could try adding `port` option with value `443`.

```
var req = https.request({
  hostname: hostname,
  port: 443,
  path: path,
  headers: {'Authorization': auth}
}, function (res){
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});

req.end();
```

Or with `auth` option instead of `header`. 
Ref: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

```
var req = https.request({
      hostname: hostname,
      port: 443,
      path: path,
      auth: username + ':' + password
    }, function (res){
      console.log(res.statusCode);
    });

    req.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

The server was expecting a User-Agent.

```
request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: url,
  headers: {'User-Agent': 'curl'},
  auth: {
    username: username,
    password: password
  }
}, function (err,res,body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

Does the job.